# Tracing logs for lambda functions in a Step Function

Tags: aws-step-functions

I am trying to find the best / most straightforward way to track / trace lambda error logs in a step function.

This particular Step Function is invoked about 350 times in parallel, when I get an error in any of the lambda functions I cant seem to find a way to get to that specific lambda invocations log as it's amongst the 350 executions.

Am I missing something? How do I get to that one specific log for the lambda?
Surely there is a way to get to the specific execution log.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use Execution.Id in your step function to match that to the id in the CloudWatch logs. You can also access timestamp. See Accessing the Context Object https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html